# find the distribution of $Y=\lceil X/2\rceil$ while $X$ distribution is geometric?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had an exam today, and there is a question that just breaks my mind.

let $X$ ~ $Geo(p)$

and let Y= $\,\left\lceil \frac{X}{2} \right\rceil $

Ii need to find the distribution of Y.

so,  i divided to 2 parts:

if X is even, so:

$P(Y=k)=$ $P(\,\left\lceil \frac{X}{2} \right\rceil=k) $ = $P(X=2k)$

and if X is odd, so:

$P(Y=k)=$ $P(\,\left\lceil \frac{X}{2} \right\rceil=k) $ = $P(X=2k-1)$

and from here and on, it's easy to continue.
is it true?

and, also,

how can I find $E[X|Y]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y = \left\lceil \frac{X}{2} \right\rceil$. Since for $k>0$
$$\{Y=k\} \equiv \{ X = 2k \} \cup \{X = 2k-1\}$$ and $\{Y=0\} \equiv \{X=0\}$, and the two events $\{X=2k\}$ and $\{X=2k-1\}$ are disjoint, we have

$$
    \Pr(Y=k) = \begin{cases} \Pr(X=0) & k = 0 \\ \Pr(X=2k) + \Pr(X=2k-1) & k > 0 \end{cases} = \begin{cases} p & k = 0 \\ p (2-p) \left(1-p\right)^{2k-1} & k > 0 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: I would be ready to believe that when the author of the exercise says "geometric" they mean $X\geqslant1$ almost surely. This option yields nicer formulas (including for E(X|Y)).

Comment: first of all, thanks.
yes, my kind of "geometric" is, $X>0$. how can if find it?